# How can i get value from subClass in Ontology by SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, ontology

diagram comme suit :
University (superclass) <-- Personne (subclass of University) <--- Student (subclass of Personne) <--- Graduation (subclass of Student)

Sub class have propert like : firstNam, lastName

I want query SPARQL to select this propery from subclass Graduation !
Thanks

Comment: aha, and you tried what so far?

Comment: and a class has no properties. that's always a wrong statement in OWL language

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking a question, please show what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has good tips.